# How do I properly compare integers of an array in an if-statement?

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I'm trying to compare a random array value with the next value, but java won't recognize the comparison in the if-statement. Eventually I'm going to need to compare each value in the array to place parenthesis around each repeated value. How can I fix this? Thank you.

```
Random rand = new Random();

    int dice[] = new int[20];

    for (int i = 0; i < dice.length; i++) {
        dice[i] = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;           //assigns values to array

    }

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(dice));     //prints whole array
    System.out.println(" ");

    if (dice[0] == dice[0] + 1) {                //right here, nothing is printed
        System.out.println("It doesn't work.");
    }
```

Comment: because you are filling array with random numbers

Comment: `dice[0] == dice[0] + 1` will never be true - think about it

Comment: @ScaryWombat oh my god, that was very stupid of me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are to compare the value of dice at index i with index i+1, and if it's equal it prints, correct?.
If that is so, here is the correction.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < dice.length - 1; i++) {
        if(dice[i] == dice[i+1]){
        System.out.println("The numbers are same at index " + i + " and " + i+1);
}

 }
```